# Subtract values in same column from 2 different dates in same redshift table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Here is an example of data I have in my table:

```
Name Age  Date
Mike 19 2020-12-12
Mike 20 2020-12-13
Blake 13 2020-12-13
Jack 28 2020-12-12
```

I'd like to get data showing the difference in age increase from 2020-12-12 and 2020-12-13. If there is no data on the 13th then show 0. If there is data on the 13th but never was on the 12th then show the new age. So given the example above I should be able to see:

```
Mike 1 
Blake 13
Jack 0
```

Comment: I don't understand why Blake is 13 but Jack is 0.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       greatest(0,
                max(case when date = '2020-12-13' then age
                         when date = '2020-12-12' then -age
                    end)
               ) as diff
from t
where t.date in ('2020-12-12', '2020-12-13')
group by name;
```